API not work when integrate kueue into Rancher
I want to emulate the integration method of ISTIO's virtualServices, gateways, and destinationRules in the Rancher, and integrate the Kueue component into the Rancher, creating Kueue's CRD and CRUD it through Rancher's API. It should be noted in advance that my Rancher here is the 2020 version, and I integrated it according to the following method
Step 1
Find the code for kueue on Github, as relying directly on Kueue in go.mod will introduce many higher versions of third-party packages, causing the Rancher project to fail to compile properly. Therefore, only a few codes of resources from kueue are extracted, and other irrelevant code is discarded. The ResourceFlavor resource structure is extracted, and the part of the code is placed under vendor/sigs.k8s.io/kueue. The resource structure of Resource Flavor is as follows:
type ResourceFlavor struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`
    Spec ResourceFlavorSpec `json:"spec,omitempty"`
}

type ResourceFlavorSpec struct {
    // +optional
    // +mapType=atomic
    // +kubebuilder:validation:MaxProperties=8
    NodeLabels map[string]string `json:"nodeLabels,omitempty"`

    // +optional
    // +listType=atomic
    // +kubebuilder:validation:MaxItems=8
    // +kubebuilder:validation:XValidation:rule="self.all(x, x.effect in ['NoSchedule', 'PreferNoSchedule', 'NoExecute'])", message="supported taint effect values: 'NoSchedule', 'PreferNoSchedule', 'NoExecute'"
    NodeTaints []corev1.Taint `json:"nodeTaints,omitempty"`

    // +optional
    // +listType=atomic
    // +kubebuilder:validation:MaxItems=8
    // +kubebuilder:validation:XValidation:rule="self.all(x, !has(x.key) ? x.operator == 'Exists' : true)", message="operator must be Exists when 'key' is empty, which means 'match all values and all keys'"
    // +kubebuilder:validation:XValidation:rule="self.all(x, has(x.tolerationSeconds) ? x.effect == 'NoExecute' : true)", message="effect must be 'NoExecute' when 'tolerationSeconds' is set"
    // +kubebuilder:validation:XValidation:rule="self.all(x, !has(x.operator) || x.operator in ['Equal', 'Exists'])", message="supported toleration values: 'Equal'(default), 'Exists'"
    // +kubebuilder:validation:XValidation:rule="self.all(x, has(x.operator) && x.operator == 'Exists' ? !has(x.value) : true)", message="a value must be empty when 'operator' is 'Exists'"
    // +kubebuilder:validation:XValidation:rule="self.all(x, !has(x.effect) || x.effect in ['NoSchedule', 'PreferNoSchedule', 'NoExecute'])", message="supported taint effect values: 'NoSchedule', 'PreferNoSchedule', 'NoExecute'"
    Tolerations []corev1.Toleration `json:"tolerations,omitempty"`
}

Step 2
Add code in types/apis/project.cattle.io/v3/schema/schema.go
func addToSchemas(fs ...func(schemas *types.Schemas) *types.Schemas) {
    l.Lock()
    defer l.Unlock()
    if Schemas == nil {
        Schemas = factory.Schemas(&Version).
            ...
            Init(resourceFlavorTypes)
    }
    if len(fs) == 0 {
        return
    }
    for _, f := range fs {
        Schemas.Init(f)
    }
}

func resourceFlavorTypes(schemas *types.Schemas) *types.Schemas {
    return schemas.
        MustImport(&Version, kueuev1beta1.ResourceFlavor{}, projectOverride{})
}

Step 3
Add the following code to types/main.go, then enter the types directory, execute make generate, and automatically generate other relevant code
kueuev1beta1 "xxx/vendor/sigs.k8s.io/kueue/v1beta1"

    generator.GenerateNativeTypes(kueuev1beta1.SchemeGroupVersion,
        []interface{}{
            kueuev1beta1.ResourceFlavor{},
        },
        nil,
    )

Step 4
Create a new pkg/api/store/resourceflavor/resourceflavor.go file
package resourceflavor

import (
    "github.com/norman/types"
)

type Store struct {
    types.Store
}

func (s *Store) Create(apiContext *types.APIContext, schema *types.Schema, data map[string]interface{}) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    return s.Store.Create(apiContext, schema, data)
}

func (s *Store) Update(apiContext *types.APIContext, schema *types.Schema, data map[string]interface{}, id string) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    return s.Store.Update(apiContext, schema, data, id)
}

func New(store types.Store) types.Store {
    return &Store{store}
}

Step 5
Add code in pkg/api/server/userstored/setup.go
func Setup(ctx context.Context, mgmt *config.ScaledContext, clusterManager *clustermanager.Manager, k8sProxy http.Handler) error {
    // Here we setup all types that will be stored in the User cluster
    schemas := mgmt.Schemas
    addProxyStore(ctx, schemas, mgmt, client.ResourceFlavorType, "kueue.x-k8s.io/v1beta1", nil)
}

ResourceFlavor(schemas)

func ResourceFlavor(schemas *types.Schemas) {
    schema := schemas.Schema(&schema.Version, client.ResourceFlavorType)
    schema.Store = resourceflavor.New(schema.Store)
}

Finally, viewing the relevant interfaces in https://localhost:8443/v3/projects/, you can see the interfaces corresponding to resourceflavor
At this point, the CRD for resource flavor has been created in Kubernetes, but clicking on it will result in error 404
$kubectl get crd | grep resourcef
resourceflavors.kueue.x-k8s.io                2024-04-07T08:06:12Z

{
"baseType": "error",
"code": "NotFound",
"message": "the server could not find the requested resource (get resourceFlavors.meta.k8s.io)",
"status": 404,
"type": "error"
}

Istio's gateway resources will also report error 404 even without relevant CRDs
{
"baseType": "error",
"code": "NotFound",
"message": "the server could not find the requested resource (get gateways.meta.k8s.io)",
"status": 404,
"type": "error"
}

But after creating the CRD for the gateway, the api will display normally and can be used to add, delete, modify, and check the gateway through the api
{
"type": "collection",
"links": {
"self": "…/v3/projects/local:p-5ws8x/gateways"
},
"createTypes": {
"gateway": "…/v3/project/local:p-5ws8x/gateways"
},
"actions": { },
"pagination": {
"limit": 1000,
"total": 0
},
"sort": {
"order": "asc",
"reverse": "…/v3/projects/local:p-5ws8x/gateways?order=desc",
"links": {
"state": "…/v3/projects/local:p-5ws8x/gateways?sort=state",
"transitioning": "…/v3/projects/local:p-5ws8x/gateways?sort=transitioning",
"transitioningMessage": "…/v3/projects/local:p-5ws8x/gateways?sort=transitioningMessage",
"uuid": "…/v3/projects/local:p-5ws8x/gateways?sort=uuid"
}
},
"filters": {
"created": null,
"creatorId": null,
"name": null,
"namespaceId": null,
"projectId": null,
"removed": null,
"state": null,
"transitioning": null,
"transitioningMessage": null,
"uuid": null
},
"resourceType": "gateway",
"data": [ ]
}

May I ask what is causing this, and where is the code written incorrectly?
